# Collective modes free Fermi gas

Tags: condensed-matter, fermions

Consider a onedimensional uncharged Fermi gas. One can compute its sound velocity as the Fermi velocity. Can this sound mode (i.e. linear dispersion) be measured? How about the two- and three-dimensional case?